# Can´t make the labels work on MDL input after i create it with append on a script;

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

This is the code that i use, im creating the input on a script using append and generating it on the container div but when the input is created the mdl label doesnt work as intended.
Im expecting it to delete label with text... when i start writing on the input created by the button but unfortunately it doesnt.
Tried using componentHandler.upgradeElement("#container"); but i cant get it to work so it upgrades the entire div with multiple labels.

```js
     
var contador=1;
    $("#somebutton").click(function () {
        contador++;
        $("#container").append(
        '<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1'+contador+'"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1'+contador+'">Text...</label></div><div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1'+contador+'"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1'+contador+'">Text...</label></div>');   
                   
    });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
       integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Simple Textfield -->
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
      </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="button" style="width:100px" id="somebutton" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Link to code
[Link to code that i use with jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/eaYTY/487/)

Comment: Please fix the question.  Posting "I'm a newbie" does not excuse posting a bad question.  Read [ask] and then create a [mcve]

Comment: There happy have no idea how to make the code go lower so here it is all in a line

Comment: Happy?  It wasn't for my benefit I took time to suggest how to better ask your question to appeal to a helpful audience more.  Yes, it is better now that someone else has done the work for you.  Good luck solving your issues.

Comment: I formatted your question so that the code is runnable. Can you explain what you are expecting? All the code does is append another button and "Text..." to the current screen.

Comment: I expected the input bellow to behave like the input above where the text.... disapears when i start to write

Comment: It explains this in the documentation.  Go to this page... https://getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic

Comment: Thanks, i have already seen this page but i dont know how to adapt it to a div container so everything inside gets upgraded with it.

Comment: Have a look below - I adapted the example to fit your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a method in the Material library for upgrading elements that you dynamically create.  You need to call this and pass it a reference to any new elements you create, in this case the container div.  Pass it as `$div[0]` so that it passes the DOM element, rather than the wrapped up jQuery object.

```js
var contador=1;

$("#somebutton").click(function () {
    contador++;

    var $div = $('<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield"><input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1'+contador+'"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1'+contador+'">Text...</label></div>');

    // tell the material library about the new elements
    componentHandler.upgradeElement($div[0]);

    $("#container").append($div);
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
       integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
       crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Simple Textfield -->
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
      </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="button" style="width:100px" id="somebutton" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Though it worked on every component inside the div but if u put the div creating more than one input its stops working.

Comment: Is that important?  You're not doing that.

Comment: i set this up as an example so it had less code to be easier to understand and thinking it would be the same if it had many but in my "real code" i have a div filled with inputs and checkboxes and am using a button to create a second line of these inputs. my mistake for thinking it would work for one or for many

Comment: but i think this will do i only have to append them in order

Comment: Yeah, I can't see an advantage of a div with just the inputs and labels in it, when the extra divs have no bearing.  It makes this part of the process (and removing them later if you want to) a lot easier.